# SignalR User NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I've got this code

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace Chat22
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string Message)
        {
            string Name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(Name, Message);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to send a message, I get `NullReferenceException` for the `Context.User.Identity.Name`

But it works fine when I set the username in my js code, and add the name as a parameter in the function, but getting the context name doesn't work.

I tried on both local and published on the web

How can I get names?

Thanks

Comment: Have you enabled authentication? http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization#requireauth

Comment: I had not! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Answer was to add authorization
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization#requireauth

Comment: Don't forget to click the tick mark to the left of the question, to mark this as solved. Thanks!